# Convergence of running maximum of U(0,1)-distributed random vaiables

Tags: probability, statistics, convergence-divergence

Let $X_1,X_2$,... be $U(0,1)$-distributed and independent random variables. Show that max$_{1\leq k\leq n} X_k \to^p 1$ as $n \to \infty$.

So I need to show that P(|max$_{1\leq k\leq n} X_k -1$|$>\epsilon$) $\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Can someone please help me? I'm stuck.

Comment: It converges even almost surely. You need to prove that $P(\max_k X_k <1-\epsilon)\to 0$, $n\to\infty$. Try to compute this probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$X_{(n)} = \max_{1 \le k \le n} X_k,$$ that is to say, $X_{(n)}$ is the maximum order statistic of the sample $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.  Then for $\epsilon > 0$, $$\Pr[|X_{(n)} - 1| > \epsilon] = 1 - \Pr[1-\epsilon \le X_{(n)} \le 1 + \epsilon] = 1 - \Pr[1 - \epsilon \le X_{(n)}] = \Pr[X_{(n)} \le 1 - \epsilon].$$  What is the cumulative distribution function of $X_{(n)}$; i.e., what is $$F_{X_{(n)}}(x) = \Pr[X_{(n)} \le x]?$$  Hint:  $X_{(n)} \le x$ if and only if **each** of $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ is less than or equal to $x$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be P$(1+\epsilon \leq X_{(n)}\leq 1 - \epsilon)$?